# Identifying layers under cursor in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, query

In QGIS 3.8, I've loaded hundreds of layers (georeferenced individual images), which are named by filename. I'm looking for a way to click on the map and query what image (i.e. what layer in the "Layers" panel) I've clicked on.

Is there a way to query a point in the map and have all layers underneath the point reported. There's plenty of tools for querying features, but I can't find anything for layers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the normal "Identify" tool for that. Just set the mode to "Layer Selection" and a list of layers at the point where you clicked will be shown. See image below:

[image]